# What were the actions of the illustrious Dronacharya, immediately before quitting his material body?

Tags: mahabharata, dronacharya

On the 15th day of the Mahabharata war, the illustrious Dronacharya laid aside his bow and other weapons, after Bhima had spoken the following words.

> He for whom thou hast taken up weapons, and for whom thou livest, he{Ashwatthama}, deprived of life, lieth today on the field of battle, unknown to thee and behind thy back. King Yudhishthira the just hath told thee this. It behoveth thee not to doubt this fact.' Thus addressed by Bhima, Drona laid aside his bow{and other weapons}.

And after Dronacharya had laid aside his weapons, Dhrishtadyumna slayed the unarmed Dronacharya.

> Disregarding, however, the cries of Arjuna, as also these of all the kings, Dhrishtadyumna slew Dronacharya, that bull among men, on the terrace of his car.

It is also pertinent to mention here, that Dhrishtadyumna had been obtained by king Drupada{Dhrishtadyumna’s father}, at a great sacrifice, from the Bearer of sacrificial libations, for the destruction of Drona.

The invincible Dronacharya, then attained to the Supreme region of Brahman.

What were the actions of the illustrious Dronacharya, immediately  before quitting his material body?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  details of the actions performed by the illustrious Dronacharya, immediately before quitting his “material” body, are explained as under.

The illustrious Dronacharya,  devoted himself to “Yoga”, after keeping aside his weapons. Dronacharya then meditated on the supreme God Vishnu. And thinking on the monosyllable Om, representing Brahma, and remembering the puissant, Supreme, and indestructible God of gods, the radiant Dronacharya of high ascetic merit, the preceptor (of the Kurus and the Pandavas) repaired to heaven.

> Drona himself abandoning his weapons, he was then in a supremely tranquil state. Having said those words{advised Karna and others to fight well}, he had devoted himself to “Yoga”.
>
> Endued with great effulgence and possessed of high ascetic merit, he had fixed his heart on that Supreme and Ancient Being, viz, Vishnu.
>
> Bending his face slightly down, and heaving his breast forward, and closing his eyes and resting it on the quality of goodness, and disposing his heart to contemplation, and thinking on the monosyllable Om, representing Brahma, and remembering the puissant, supreme, and indestructible God of gods, the radiant Drona of high ascetic merit, the preceptor (of the Kurus and the Pandavas) repaired to heaven that is so difficult of being attained even by the pious.
>
> In fact, all human beings were unconscious of the fact that the preceptor attained to the supreme region of Brahman, a region mysterious to the very gods, and one that is the highest of all. Indeed, none of them could see the preceptor, that chastiser of foes, proceed to the region of Brahman, devoted to Yoga in the company of the foremost of Rishis.
>
> Only we five amongst men beheld the high-souled Drona rapt in Yoga proceed to the highest region of blessedness
>
> These five were myself{Sanjaya}, Dhananjaya, the son of Pritha, and Drona's son, Aswatthaman, and Vasudeva of Vrishni's race, and king Yudhishthira the just, the son of Pandu. Nobody else, O king, could see that glory of the wise Drona, devoted to Yoga, while passing out of the world.

These actions of Dronacharya, which were centred in Yoga, before attaining to the Supreme region of Brahman, were as per the "sacred truths" given in

[SB 1.9.23.](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/9/23)

> SB 1.9.23 — The Personality of Godhead, who appears in the mind of the devotee by attentive devotion and meditation and by chanting of the holy name, releases the devotee from the bondage of fruitive activities at the time of his quitting the material body.

Excerpt of the Purport

> Yoga means concentration of the mind detached from all other subject matter. And actually such concentration is Samādhi, or cent-percent engagement in the service of the Lord. The Lord calls such a rare devotee the best amongst all the yogīs. Such a perfect Yogī is enabled by the divine grace of the Lord to concentrate his mind upon the Lord with a perfect sense of consciousness, and thus by chanting His holy name before quitting the body the Yogī is at once transferred by the internal energy of the Lord to one of the eternal planets where there is no question of material life and its concomitant factors.

The complete details of the event, are given in the Mahabharata Book:7,Drona Parva, [Drona-Vadha Parva.](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07189.htm)